# How application run multiple bound services with same authorities and same account type using Sync Adapter class?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have customized Odoo Android SDK. 
https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework
In the sdk only one Customer service  is working using Syncadapter. I have implemented messaging service also. but app can not work both service at a time.I can get either messaging data or customers data.

**When i run the application it is running only one service at a time.
How can i run MessagingSyncService and CustomerSyncService Services at a time ?** can any one help me it would be appriciated. thanks in advance

```
<provider
           android:name="com.odoo.addons.messaging.providers.MessagingSyncProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.core.provider.content.sync.res_partner"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_messaging"
                android:multiprocess="true" />


        <service
            android:name="com.odoo.addons.messaging.services.MessagingSyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync_messaging">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/messaging_sync_adapter" />
        </service>


  <provider
            android:name="com.odoo.addons.customers.providers.CustomersSyncProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.core.provider.content.sync.res_partner"
            android:label="@string/sync_label_customers"
            android:multiprocess="true" />

        <service
            android:name="com.odoo.addons.customers.services.CustomerSyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync_customer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/customer_sync_adapter" />
        </service>
```

**Sync_adater.xml**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.odoo.auth"
    android:contentAuthority="com.odoo.core.provider.content.sync.res_partner"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

Comment: post java code ...

Comment: i can not underdtand that which java code should i give you. i have customized Odoo Android SDK. in the sdk only one service like contact is working using Syncadapter. I have implemented messaging service also. but app can not work both service at a time.

Comment: i mean how you start services?

Comment: i have used https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework java code